# Is quantum field invariant under change of same type of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

The evolution of states Schrodinger picture
$|\psi(t)\rangle=U\left(t\right)\left|\psi\left(0\right)\right\rangle$

Where
$$U(t)=\mathrm{T} \exp \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} H\left(t^{\prime}\right) d t^{\prime}\right)$$

Assuming that the the Hamiltonian is a function of $n$ fields $\phi_i$ that is
$H=H(\phi_1,...\phi_n)$. If  we make a change of variables
$$\phi_i=F(\chi_i) \tag 1$$

Then we would have $$H(\phi_1,...\phi_n)=H'(\chi_1,...\chi_n)$$

Where the field $\chi_i$ is of the same type of the field $\phi$ in the sense that we can obtain one by Taylor expansion of the other.

My question is, does the  physical result  remains unchanged if we make the substitution $(1)$?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by obtaining one from the other in the sense of Taylor expanding. Can you be more clear about it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, scattering matrix elements (and in general, any observable) are invariant under local, invertible field redefinitions.

I think Coleman discusses this in detail in his Erice lectures.